# iOS - NSLocalNotification- set notification every other day

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I want to set a Local Notification every other day (multiplication on NSDayCalendarUnit), How can I achieve this?

So far, I've done this:

```
- (void)scheduleLocalNotication {

    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    
    // Set the fire date/time
    [localNotification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
    [localNotification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
    
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    
    // Setup alert notification
    [localNotification setAlertAction:@"Open App"];
    [localNotification setAlertBody:@"setAreltBody"];
    [localNotification setAlertBody:@"You had set a Local Notification on this time"];
    
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [localNotification setHasAction:YES];
    
    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [app scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

Can I change this line:

`localNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;`

to something like this:

`localNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit * 2;`

I guess not, since NSDayCalendarUnit is a `typedef`, so how can I do this?

Comment: You mean you want it to be set every **second** day, right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible using the `repeatInterval` property of `UILocalNotification`, for the same reason that you already pointed out, `NSCalendarUnit` is an *enum*, so you can only use the following values:
[image: values]

An alternative option would be to schedule a number of notifications in a loop and always add 24 hours to the previous fire date.